# telnet connects without socket being accepted

Tags: c, linux, sockets, telnet, epoll

Here is a minimal example code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NPROTO 10000
#define LOCALHOST "127.0.0.1"

/* */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int                 sfd, epfd;
 struct sockaddr_in  so_address;
 struct epoll_event  ev, evs[1];

 sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
 if(sfd < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 epfd = epoll_create(1);
 if(epfd < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 memset(&so_address, 0, sizeof(so_address));
 so_address.sin_family       = AF_INET;
 so_address.sin_port         = htons(NPROTO);
 if(1 != inet_pton(AF_INET, LOCALHOST, (struct in_addr*)(&so_address.sin_addr.s_addr))){
  fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton() failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 if(bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&so_address, sizeof(so_address)) < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "bind() failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 if(listen(sfd, 4) < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "listen() failed\n");
  exit(1);
 } 

 ev.data.fd = sfd;
 ev.events  = 0;
 epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &ev);

 epoll_wait(epfd, evs, 1, -1);

 return 0;
}
```

The code creates socket that listens for the connections and registers the socket with an `epoll` set. Last lines wait for the activity on a epoll set.

Note that `events` flags of a `struct epoll_event` is set to `zero`. With the above example code, `telnet` connects to the program. If I change the flags to `EPOLLIN`, `telnet` reports "Connection refused".

The question is, why `telnet` connects whithout an accept being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the port that `telnet` connects to is available after the `listen`.

In all [your] cases, `telnet` sees a connection established.

When you do `ev.events = 0;`, the `epoll_wait` will wait forever.

When you do `ev.events = EPOLLIN`, the `epoll_wait` will return. But, since you have nothing after that, `main` returns and the socket is closed when the server terminates. That is what `telnet` sees (e.g. `Connection closed by foreign host.`)

If you do:

```
printf("running ...\n");
while (1)
    sleep(1);
```

after the `epoll_wait`, then `telnet` will see the same effect, regardless of the value of `ev.events`

Comment: Ok, I understood the part of your answer about socket being closed. But I still do not understand how is it that `telnet` just connects to a port? Is it `telnet` specifics? I thought one needs to `accept()` a socket. BTW I had waited for some time for `telnet` connection to be timed out, but it is not.

Comment: @user14063792468 `accept()` is required to create a socket for communication with client but SYN/ACK handshake is performed by TCP stack before `accept()` is called.